# how to get value from session in Razor View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

in Core 2.1:
I set the value in controller

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("IsAuthenticated", "true");
```

when i get the value in view.cshtml, the value is null

```
if (Context.Session.GetString("IsAuthenticated") == "true")
```

Comment: You can visit the page to refer more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code in an app I have and it worked. It would seem to me that you haven't set up the use of cookies in your app. Try the following:

```
// The following goes into ConfigureServices in Startup.cs
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
});
```

Having done that, you'll still need one more thing to set it up in the `Configure` method in Startup.cs

```
// place after the other app.UseFoo methods. 
app.UseSession();
```

Comment: Of course I added this to Startup, but this is useless.
@Fabulous